# Android NDK C library causes seg fault

Tags: android, c, segmentation-fault, android-ndk

I'm having some trouble with c code from a library that I use with Android NDK.

It works on the emulator, but not on a real device. It gives me a "libc - Fatal signal 11" (SIGSEGV)

I have traced the problem to a piece of code in the library, but I'm having trouble understanding what the second line does.

Here is the code:

```
int lookup_mpz(mpz_t z, const char *(*tab)(const char *), const char *key) {
  const char *data= tab(key); //--> Causes SEGV
  if (!data) {
    pbc_error("missing param: `%s'", key);
    return 1;
  }
  mpz_set_str(z, tab(key), 0);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second line is invoking a function, via a function pointer named `tab`. The function has the signature:

```
const char* f(const char*);
```

Suggest checking that `key` and `tab()` are not NULL prior to calling `tab()`.

Comment: Why not check `tab` as it's a pointer also? I think in case when NULL passed to `tab` it would cause SIGSEGV in it's implementation, not in `lookup_mpz`

Comment: Thanks that helps. I just cant find that function tab() anywhere, that might be the problem. But that still doesn't explain why the code works on the emulator but not on the real device.

Comment: There may not be a function named `tab()`, that is the name of the function pointer. Suggest looking for where `lookup_mpz()` is invoked, if possible, and checking the arguments passed to it.

Comment: O yeah, that makes sense. I'll have a look.